# How to get dates where value changed in rows of date/value tuples?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got a table (actually a subquery result) with tuples of `DATE` and `NUMBER`. Dates are gapless and ordered in a given timespan.

```
countdate  | countvalue
-----------------------
2014-01-01 | 5
2014-01-02 | 5
2014-01-03 | 5
2014-01-04 | 4
2014-01-05 | 4
2014-01-06 | 4
2014-01-07 | 5
```

How can I select all countdates (with corresponding countvalue) where countvalue changed in comparison to the previous day?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Oracle 11g, but ANSI SQL solution would be nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ANSI standard `lag()` function does what you want:

```
select s.countdate, s.countvalue
from (select s.*, lag(countvalue) over (order by countdate) as prevvalue
      from (<subquery>) s
     ) s
where prevvalue is null or prevvalue <> countvalue;
```